# Generating Swagger-based API method listing in MVC's cshtml page

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, swagger

I have two company executives, and their companies are different. I'm trying to list the employees working under these company executives based on their IDs using the `GetAllByCompany` method in the API. You can see the method below:

```
// GET: api/<UserController>
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<UserDetailDTO>>> GetAllByCompany(int id)
{
    var user = await _userService.GetAll(id);
    return Ok(user);
}
```

According to this method, the output we get in Swagger is as follows:

```json
{
  "errors": [],
  "hasError": false,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "imagePath": "\\images\\ikrafoto.png",
      "firstName": "İkra",
      "secondName": "Gamze",
      "lastName": "YILMAZ",
      "secondLastName": "DEMİR",
      "birthDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "birthPlace": "Çorum",
      "tcNo": "12312312312",
      "dateOfStart": "2023-05-15T00:00:00",
      "dateOfExit": null,
      "companyName": "Bilge Adam",
      "jobName": "Software Developer",
      "department": "BackEnd Developer",
      "address": "Anıttepe Neighborhood, Gül Street, 139/D No:18  Alaca/ÇORUM",
      "isActive": true,
      "email": "ikra.gamze@bilgeadamboost.com",
      "phoneNumber": "555555555"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "imagePath": "\\images\\ecmel1.png",
      "firstName": "Emel",
      "secondName": null,
      "lastName": "ÖZ",
      "secondLastName": "YAVUZ",
      "birthDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "birthPlace": "Bolu",
      "tcNo": "11111111111",
      "dateOfStart": "2021-05-15T00:00:00",
      "dateOfExit": "2021-06-23T00:00:00",
      "companyName": "Bilge Adam",
      "jobName": "Software Engineer Intern",
      "department": "Intern",
      "address": "Beşiktaş Neighborhood, İnönü Street, Kartal Alley No:12  Mamak/ANKARA",
      "isActive": false,
      "email": "emel.oz@bilgeadamboost.com",
      "phoneNumber": "55555555555"
    }
  ]
}
```

The action in my `CompanyManagerController` in ASP.NET Core MVC is as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<PersonnelListVM>>> ListPersonnel()
{
    var responseTask = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"api/user");

    if (responseTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseContent = await responseTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PersonnelListVM>>(responseContent);
        return View(users); 
    }

    return View();
}
```

In the `.cshtml` page, I write `List<PersonnelListVM>`, but in the foreach loop inside it, I get the error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.Model.get returned null.

I would be very happy if you could help.

In my `ListPersonnel` action, I tried replacing

```
DeserializeObject<List<PersonnelListVM>>(responseContent)
```

with

```
DeserializeObject<PersonnelListVM>(responseContent)
```

and I also removed the 'List' part from @model section in the `.cshtml` page. However, I had to revert these changes because I need to display a list in the cshtml page.

Answer (score 0):

> I write List, but in the foreach loop inside it, I
> get the error:
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
> of an object.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.Model.get returned null.

About this issue, if you set a break point to check your code, the users might be null or empty, so it will show this error.

According to the Swagger output, if you want to Deserialize Object from the JSON response, you should use the following model: RootModel and PersonnelListVM:

```
public class PersonnelListVM
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string imagePath { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string secondName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string secondLastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime birthDate { get; set; }
    public string birthPlace { get; set; }
    public string tcNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateOfStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime? dateOfExit { get; set; }
    public string companyName { get; set; }
    public string jobName { get; set; }
    public string department { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
}
public class RootModel
{
    public List<object> errors { get; set; }
    public bool hasError { get; set; }
    public List<PersonnelListVM> data { get; set; }
}
```

Then, when Deserialize Object from the JSON response, deserialize the Json result to the RootModel, and then get the Personnel list from the RootModel. use the following code:

```
        var responseTask = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"api/user");

        if (responseTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseContent = await responseTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var users = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootModel>(responseContent)).data;
            return View(users);
        }
```

The output as below:

[image]

[**Update**]

As we can see that action method returned model is matches the model in the view page.
The action code:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ListPersonnelAsync()
    { 
        var _httpClient = _httpclientfactory.CreateClient();
        _httpClient.BaseAddress=new Uri("https://localhost:7012");
        var responseTask = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"api/user");

        if (responseTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseContent = await responseTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            List<PersonnelListVM> users = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootModel>(responseContent)).data;
            return View(users);
        }  
        return View(); 
    }
```

The view page:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication8.Models.PersonnelListVM>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ListPersonnel";
}

<h1>ListPersonnel</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.imagePath)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.firstName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.secondName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.lastName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.secondLastName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.birthDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.birthPlace)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tcNo)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dateOfStart)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dateOfExit)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.companyName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.jobName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.department)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.address)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.isActive)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.email)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.phoneNumber)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.imagePath)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.firstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.secondName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.secondLastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.birthDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.birthPlace)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tcNo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dateOfStart)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dateOfExit)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.companyName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.jobName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.department)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.address)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.isActive)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.phoneNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Despite making all the updates, I am still getting the strange error below.                                                                                                                                                   
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[HRManagementProject.MVC.Areas.CompanyManager.Models.ViewModels.PersonelListVM]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'HRManagementProject.MVC.Areas.CompanyManager.Models.ViewModels.CompanyManagerDetailVM'.

Comment: About the InvalidOperationException exception, it means that in the action method, you will return a list of PersonelListVM, but in the view page, the page model is a CompanyManagerDetailVM, they are not match, so it will show this error. To solve it, in the view page, you can change the page model to a list of PersonelListVM.

Comment: Please check the update in the above, as we can see that action method returned model is matches the model in the view page.